# Alter table with timestamp with time zone need to migrate old data or not

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a requirement that need to change a table where i was using timestamp without time zone to timestamp with time zone in postgres. Required table already populated with old data so if i try:

```
 ALTER TABLE mytable ALTER COLUMN createdat TYPE timestamp with time zone;
```

Should this change all the existing records or not ?.
I have seen a change but not sure is this really adding a timezone entry("Europe/London") in record or not.

Record without time zone:`2017-05-15 02:19:02.443` and when alter table and adding timestamp with time zone: `2017-05-14 05:47:43.523+00`

I can confirm current time zone by running this on my db:

```
SELECT  current_setting('TIMEZONE')
```

Europe/London

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`timestamp with time zone` does not store time zone information in PostgreSQL, it stores an UTC timestamp that is converted to the session time zone upon retrieval.

The `ALTER TABLE` you show will interpret the `timestamp without time zone` values in the current session time zone, so if all your data are to be interpreted in the `Europe/London` time zone, the result should be correct.

If you need to store the time zone of the timestamp, e.g. to preserve the input time zone, you'll have to store the time zone as a separate field.

```
SHOW TimeZone;
┌───────────────┐
│   TimeZone    │
├───────────────┤
│ Europe/Vienna │
└───────────────┘
(1 row)

CREATE TABLE mytime(
   id integer PRIMARY KEY,
   ts timestamp without time zone NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO mytime VALUES (1, '2017-05-15 12:00:00');

SELECT * FROM mytime;
┌────┬─────────────────────┐
│ id │         ts          │
├────┼─────────────────────┤
│  1 │ 2017-05-15 12:00:00 │
└────┴─────────────────────┘
(1 row)

ALTER TABLE mytime ALTER ts TYPE timestamp with time zone;

SELECT * FROM mytime;
┌────┬────────────────────────┐
│ id │           ts           │
├────┼────────────────────────┤
│  1 │ 2017-05-15 12:00:00+02 │
└────┴────────────────────────┘
(1 row)
```

If I change my time zone, the values displayed change:

```
SET TimeZone = 'Asia/Kolkata';

SELECT * FROM mytime;
┌────┬───────────────────────────┐
│ id │            ts             │
├────┼───────────────────────────┤
│  1 │ 2017-05-15 15:30:00+05:30 │
└────┴───────────────────────────┘
(1 row)
```

Comment: Well adding a new record in alter table are showing like this: "2017-05-15 14:12:19.26491+02" I am confused that what going wrong with existing records after alter table with time zone

Comment: Well as i mentioned above existing dates are showing like this: 2017-05-14 05:47:43.523+00. and a when i adding a new data dates field looks like this: 2017-05-15 14:12:19.26491+02. I just want to confirm are the existing dates now converted with time zone or not?

Comment: Yes, they are, and I don't believe that if you run `SELECT * FROM mytable`, you can get some values displayed with `+00` and others with `+02` time zone offset. All values will be shown in the same time zone, namely the session time sone set with the `TimeZone` parameter.